# How to copy/move files from ubuntu to windows machine using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have one requirement copy/move the files from ubuntu machine to windows machine.

Can anybody assist on this?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you get an application called [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) installed on your Windows server. This is free and very easy to use.

It is like an FTP application, using your Linux username and password (along with the SSH port). This way, all future copies between these OS'es will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have any third-party server software installed on your Windows machine, your best bet is samba. You can pre-setup the samba shares on your windows machine, connect to them from ubuntu and then use them from your ruby code as they would be local files and directories.

```
FileUtils.cp 'eval.c', 'eval.c.org'
```

[Example from Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-copy).

If you want to manage samba connections from ruby, one gem that might help is [sambal](https://github.com/johnae/sambal).

If you are willing to install software to your Windows machine, follow the advice of @Mark and install WinSCP. This will bring much more secured transport which you will be able to use with a little help of [net-scp gem](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-scp).

```
Net::SCP.upload!("remote.host.com", "username",
  "/local/path", "/remote/path",
  :ssh => { :password => "password" })

# download a file from a remote server
Net::SCP.download!("remote.host.com", "username",
  "/remote/path", "/local/path",
  :ssh => { :password => "password" })
```